# If $first is the only operator inside of $group, will it be much faster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

$group is slow and may exceed the 100mb limit for an aggregation stage because it must wait for all incoming documents before output.

However if your aggregation is something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
                  $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    name: { $first: "$name" },
                  }
}
]}
```

Will MongoDB be smart enough to recognize that it doesn't need to wait for all incoming records? Because it can just output the first document it finds?

Comment: Probably not. That sounds like a great feature request, though

Comment: This example isn't particularly great as, typically, the incoming `_id` field is unique so the sample `$group` here is really just an expensive way to do a `$project`. But generally, MongoDB does not perform streaming `$group` for situations like this today. Nevertheless, there is a special index traversal technique that will be used for aggregations like this if there is an appropriate underlying index. See `$group` stage section [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#indexes)